# flux through a line complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a velocity field, say
 $$
\mathbb{v}=\left\langle\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2},\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right\rangle
$$ 
First, I have to find the complex velocity potential, then I have to calculate the flux across a straight line from $2i$ to $1$ in the direction right to left.

So for the complex velocity potential, since this velocity field is both irrotational and incompressible $\phi$ and $\psi$ exists. thus the complex velocity is 
$$
\Psi(x,y)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)
$$
where the complex velocity potential here is 
$$
\Psi(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
I am not sure that this is correct.

Lastly, the flux of $$\mathbb{v}=\int_\gamma\big(V\cdot n)d\vec{s}=\int_\gamma Pdy-Qdx$$

but this does not seem right, as I have a variable of two unknowns but only a 1D argument/input? Maybe if I use greens theorem?

""""Edit"""""

So if I do this into a surface integral using greens theorem

$$\int Pdy-Qdx = \iint \Big(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\Big)dxdy$$

But how would I know which limits I can use for which variables and how would one know the limit for the other variable, lets say that I use $2i$ to $1$ for $x$  how would I know what to use for $y$?

Comment: Green's theorem is for a closed contour.  You can compute the line integral over a segment directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the velocity components as

$$u = \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \,\,\, v = \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

The complex potential is an analytic function $\Psi(z) = \phi(x,y) + i \psi(x,y)$ of the complex variable $z = x+iy$ where the  real part $\phi$ is the velocity potential and the imaginary part $\psi$ is the streamfunction.

Applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations we obtain

$$u = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y},\,\,\,  v= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}   $$

We can solve for $\phi$ by integrating first $u$ with respect to $x$,

$$\phi = \int \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dx = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} + C(y)$$

Taking the derivative with respect to y we obtain

$$v = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} + C'(y) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} + C'(y)$$

This implies that $C'(y) = 0$ and $C(y)$ is a constant which can be set arbitrarily to zero.

Thus, $\phi(x,y) = y/(x^2+y^2)$ and in a similar way we can find $\psi(x,y) = x/(x^2+y^2)$. The complex potential is then given by

$$\Psi(z) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} + i \frac{x}{x^2+ y^2}$$

We can compute the flux as a contour integral of the complex velocity $u -iv$, where the contour is the line segment with endpoints $1$ and $2i$. Equivalently, we can use a line integral in the real plane over the segment $C= \{(\mu(t),\lambda(t)) = (1-t, 2t): \, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1\}.$

Using the latter approach, we have

$$\text{flux} = \int_C \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n}\, ds,$$

where

$$\mathbf{n} = \left\langle\frac{-\lambda'(t)}{\sqrt{\mu'(t)^2 + \lambda'(t)^2}}, \frac{\mu'(t)}{\sqrt{\mu'(t)^2 + \lambda'(t)^2}} \right\rangle = \langle -2/\sqrt{3}, -1/\sqrt{3}\rangle,$$

$\mathbf{v} = \langle u(\mu(t), \lambda(t)), v(\mu(t), \lambda(t)) \rangle$ and $ds = \sqrt{\mu'(t)^2 + \lambda'(t)^2} dt = \sqrt{3} dt$.

You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: you said that $\phi(x,y) = y/x^2+y^2$ yet in the complex velocity potential you write that $\Psi(z) = x/x^2+y^2 + iy/x^2+y^2$. How?

Comment: I think it should be $\Psi(z) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ if im not mistaken.

Comment: Using the line integral over the real plane i got that $I=-1$ does this seem correct?

Comment: also if I were to use the contour integral instead, what would i be integrating with respect to?

Comment: @user8700908: Yes — you are correct about the potential. Sorry for the typos which I now fixed.  I’ll get back to you on the  line integral questions.

Comment: I also get that the flux is $I = -1$. I checked with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I have to think further on how to write the flux as a complex contour integral.

Comment: @user8700908:  SInce multiplication of a complex number by $i$ represents rotation of the associated vector by 90 degrees, the contour integral representation of the flux should be $\int_C (u-iv)\,i\, dz$ where $dz = (\mu'(t ) + i\lambda'(t))dt = (-1 + 2i) dt$.  The real part of this integral is the physical flux and will coincide with what we computed.  In practice it is never computed this way as far as I know. Even if the complex potential is used the flux is computed as a line integral in the real plane.